# Linking installed apps to android market

Tags: android

How to link manually installed apps to android market?
[Titanium Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) and [MyBackup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupPro) provide this feature.

Answer (score 0):

@Koustubh Yadav I being in that situation before the best advice I can provide and which works best for me is adding an additional "manual update" button linking the device to your host where the new .apk will be uploaded too and fire off a download to download and install your new apk. By default Android will ask if the User wishes to replace the current version ... at which point the User will make the independent choice to update the .apk or refuse.

Answer (score -1):

you would use an intent.

```
String marketURL = "blah";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(marketURL));
startActivity(intent);
```

If this is not what you want, please explain what you want....in more detail...

Comment: What he is asking for is quite clear. If you install APKs from non-market sources they will not be updated even if they are present in the market. Linking an app to the Market makes it visible and updateable. Unlinking and app makes it invisible to the Market.